# Bootloop after CWM Restore

Tags: boot-loop

I have a Good Backup from CWM, after installing chainfire 3d, It went to boot loop, I restore the device through CWM, but the device is still in boot loop,.

dmesg.log http://pastebin.com/1u4PGhsr

recoovery.log http://pastebin.com/GKKsiN7N

How come my device is in bootloop if I have a good backup? :(

Answer (score 0):

pefrom Factory Reset \ Clear Cache after the CWM Restore ,  the old Rom must save data you must delete in order for the CWM to work.

Comment: Don't you mean *before* CWM restore?